# Powershell - Creating an 2D array inside a class

Tags: arrays, class, 2d

I'm trying to create a "matrix / multidimensional array) inside a class function whit a loop.

Also (because I'm used to other languages) couldn't get it to work.

Is there somebody who could help me to get this working / or could explain to me what I'm doing wrong?

```
Class Matrix {
    [int]$row
    [int]$column
    [int]$counter
    $data

    Matrix() {
        Write-Host "No rows and columns provided"
    }

    Matrix($row, $column){
        #Write-Host "row = " $row " column = " $column
        $array = @(,@())

        for ($i=0;$i -le $row -1 ; $i++) {
            #Write-Host "This is row number " + $i

            for ($j=0;$j -le $column -1 ; $j++) {
                #Write-Host "This is column number " + $j
                #00,01,02..10,11,12..
                $array[$i][$j] = 2
            }
        }

        $this.row = $row
        $this.column = $column
        $this.counter = 0
        $this.data = $array
    }

    [void]add($adder){
        if ($adder.GetType().name -eq "Matrix"){
            Write-Host "You had given a matrix not a number"
        }Else{
            $this.counter = $this.counter + $adder
        }
    }
}

$matrix1 = [Matrix]::New(4,3)
$matrix1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it :)
for the people who are searching this , here is the code I used :

```
Matrix($row,$col){
    $temp_array = New-Object 'object[,]' $row,$col #<<<<============

    for ($i=0;$i -le $row -1 ; $i++) {
        for ($j=0;$j -le $col -1 ; $j++) {
            $temp_array[$i,$j] = Get-Random -Minimum 0 -Maximum 10 
        }
    }

    $this.row = $row
    $this.col = $col
    $this.counter = 0
    $this.prosessed = 0
    $this.data = $temp_array #<<<<============
}
```